# Clicking element type

Tags: jquery

Alright so I am basically trying to hide specified element when someone clicks outside of the form but the problem is, nothing actually works

```
$("#overlayBG").click(function(e) {
    if(e.target === "form") {
        $("#overlayBG").hide();
    } else {
        console.log("Form not clicked");
    }
});
```

Basically the output I am getting is "Form not clicked"

Comment: Can you post your html code so that we can check

Comment: `event.target` isn't a string, therefore `event.target === "form"` will always be false. You either need to check against the element name, or compare it with an actual DOM element. To get the element's tag name, use `event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()`.... or since you're using jQuery, use the `.is()` method... `$(event.target).is('form')`.

Comment: Josh is right, if you want to check it for yourself then try console.log(e.target);

Comment: This is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5t9jmf7e/6/

Answer (score 0):

$ ( "body" ).click( function( e ) {

```
if ( e.target.id != "overlayBG" ) {

    $( "#overlayBG" ).hide( );

} else {

    console.log( "overlayBG is clicked" );

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments:

You are comparing the object [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to a string. Therefore `event.target === "form"` will always be false. You either need to check against the element name, or compare it with an actual DOM element.

For instance, to get the element's tag name, use `event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()`. Alternatively, since you're using jQuery, you could use the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$("#overlayBG").click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is('form')) {
    $("#overlayBG").hide();
  } else {
    alert("The form was clicked...");
  }
});
```

However, that will only check to see if `event.target` is a `form` element (which won't work when clicking the children elements of the form). Therefore you should traverse the DOM and check to see if the closest ancestor element is a `form` element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/r752bcb7/)

```
$("#overlayBG").click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('form').length) {
    $("#overlayBG").hide();
  } else {
    alert("The form was clicked...");
  }
});
```

Additionally, if you want to listen to *all* click events:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/r0r39utz/)

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#overlayBG form').length) {
    $("#overlayBG").hide();
  } else {
    alert("The form was clicked...");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5t9jmf7e/7/)

What I usually do is I get the target's id and use that as my reference point.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="overlayBG">
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder "some text..." />
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlayBG {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

form {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

JS

```
$("#overlayBG").click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id === "overlayBG") {
    $("#overlayBG").hide();
  } else {
    alert("Form not clicked");
  }
});
```

Here's the key thing

```
var id = $(this).attr('id'); //Get id of the clicked element
      if (id === "overlayBG") { //Check if the id is what you're looking for
        $("#overlayBG").hide();
      }
```